# Integrating MS dynamic CRM 2016 with HTML web page form

Tags: javascript, html, soap, wsdl, dynamics-crm

I want to integrate MS Dynamics CRM 2016 with a website form (HTML page). When the form in the website is submitted, a contact record has to be created in CRM. Is there anyway to achieve this using JavaScript, SOAP, etc..

Comment: Grab Xrm.Tooling.Connector from NuGet and check out the related MSDN entries for the easiest way to do stuff with CRM

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a contact in CRM from an HTML page via the [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx). Your HTTP POST would look like:

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/contacts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json
{
    "name": "Stack Overflow",
    "address1_street1": "My House",
    "description": "This is the description"
}
```

You will require additional authentication unless your HTML page is hosted within CRM as, for example, an iFrame on an entity form, or as the configuration page for a solution. Authentication is passed as an HTML header like so:

`Authentication: 'Bearer' + token` where `token` is an OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token.

If your HTML page is part of an external application you might want to look into registering your Dynamics CRM organisation with Azure. You'd then be able to use Azure's [Active Directory Authentication Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) (ADAL).

Comment: My HTML page is part of an external application. I'm new to webservice. can you explain me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XRMServiceToolkit libraries(javascript) & create/update new records in CRM. To consume Web API you need to attach your instance with Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at free wordpress plug-in at https://alexacrm.com

This may be the fastest and quickest way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Soap as well as Rest API to connect do Dynamics CRM. I have done prior using PHP . If your application is in PHP than you can refer to below sample code.

https://bitbucket.org/nigelheap/msdynamicsphp-master/downloads/

If you want to use REST API of Dynamics CRM than you need to host Dynamics CRM API to Azure Active Directory & than you will be able to use that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt622431.aspx